# Where are resource strings kept? Are they editable in the Admin

Tags: configuration

In our item detail page, category listing and search results, I need to change the verbiage "Regular Price" to "MSRP".  I'm new to Magento so I don't know if string resources are kept in a separate string resource file or if they are embedded in the template code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, labels of the attributes can be changed in **Catalog** > **Attributes** > **Manage Attributes** > **Manage Label / Options** section of the selected attribute.

Unfortunately, price isn't simple attribute and in your particular case "Regular Price" string is part of product price template, which is stored in folowing file:

**app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/product/price.phtml**

which should be modified according to your needs. Another question is why not to use built-in MSRP attribute to show suggested retail price?

Comment: Use the translate table, only mess up templates for real programming issues. Saves you a lot of grief down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Have a gander at a previous SO question (I'm sure there are plenty more if you search for them):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495235/translating-magento-frontend

While it might not be what you're after, Magento's translation mechanism will allow you to modify anything echoed with `$this->__('Some String')` by using the translation files. If you're interested in keeping things tidy and edits all in one spot, I'd use this instead of modifying template files.

Comment: Don't edit templates when translation does it all for you. Instead of mucking up an otherwise stock template just for a label change, put it in the translation CSV in the form of `"Old Term","New Term"` in your `/var/www/magento/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/my_template/locale/en_US/translate.csv` file, en_US being the folder for US English, substitute standard locale designation for your language.